# DataGridComboBoxColumn set ItemSource based on selected item of another DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have 2 DataGridComboBoxColumn in my datagrid ClassificationComboBox & DisclosureNoteComboBox. 
The first one works ok, I see it populated with data.
What i want is that when an item is selected in the first one i.e. ClassificationComboBox , I want the second one to display a list of data from the selected Item in the first one.
The selected Item in ClassificationComboBox is of type Classification and this has a list called ClassificationRecords which I want populated in the DisclosureNoteComboBox.

This is a snippet of my XML.

```
              <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Classification" IsEditable="False" x:Name="ClassificationComboBox"
                                                       ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ElementName=TrialBalanceViewName, Path=Report.Classifications}"
                                                       DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                       SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                                                       SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ClassificationRecord.ClassificationId}"
                                                       />
                <materialDesign:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Disclosure Note" IsEditable="False" x:Name="DisclosureNoteComboBox"
                                                       ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ElementName=ClassificationComboBox, Path=SelectedValueBinding.ClassificationRecords}"
                                                       SelectedValuePath="DisclosureNote"
                                                       SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ClassificationRecord.DisclosureNote}"
                                                       />
```

I suspect my problem is how to construct the ItemsSourceBinding for the second one (especially the path). I think this is wrong but I am unsure how to call the selected Item of the first one and call ClassificationRecords on it to be the ItemSource of the second one

```
ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding ElementName=ClassificationComboBox, Path=SelectedValueBinding.ClassificationRecords}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't approach the problem like this because data grid columns definitions do not contain the data you want. They are instructions to the DataGrid on how to display its items, and not containers of the items themselves.

To solve this you need to bind to the data model, not the column definitions.

- Column A: binds to property `foo`.
- Column B: binds to property `bar`
  with an ItemsSource populated by property `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solved my problem. What I did was created a property on each row that exposes a list which is used as the item source for the second combo box based on the value of the first combo box.